# Maximum value of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of doubles and I need to get the maximum value within it and then store the value inside an integer variable so that I can compare the value. I have this so far:

```
vector<double>::iterator result;

result = max_element(zerocrossdata.begin(), zerocrossdata.end());
```

How can I place the value inside a variable?

Comment: Confused? Try [reading the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)!

Comment: Did you mean to say "store the value inside a *double* variable"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deference the iterator using the * operator, as has already been stated by others:

```
int max_value = *result;
```

However, be aware that the result of this operation will be a **double**, not an int. On almost all platforms, double will be an 8 byte floating point value. Your result could be outside the range of values an int (typically a signed 4-byte integer) can support. This could result in unexpected behaviour, and you may (or may not) get a compiler warning about it, depending on your compiler and settings.

Comment: My answer with `int` was just a typo. I've updated it to use the correct type of `double`.

Comment: The original question does ask how to "store the value inside an integer variable". So your original answer did actually do that, and I wasn't suggesting it was wrong.

Answer (score 10):

The `std::max_element()` function returns an iterator pointing to the maximum element in the vector.

So to get the actual maximum value you just need to dereference the returned iterator like so:

```
double max_value = *result;
```

Comment: don't forget to check if `result != std::end(zerocrossdata)`

Comment: that is true, but I think a better check would be to verify `!zerocrossdata.empty()` before even calling `max_element()`.